# Insert shape without SELECT

Tags: vba, excel

A piece of my code goes through a range of cells and if some cell satisfies certain criteria - inserts the shape in this cell. It works, but I would like to find out an alternative approach avoiding `select`.

```
'above - code to find satisfying cell
ActWS.Activate       'Activate Sheet
ActWS.Cells(rActPlan - 1, vReturnColumn).Select 'Select satisfying cell
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, ActiveCell.Width, ActiveCell.Height).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
 With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .Weight = 2.25
 End With
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code removes all `.Select` and `ActiveCell` references:

```
With ActWs

    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = .Cells(rActPlan - 1, vReturnColumn)

    Dim shp as Shape
    Set shp = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)

    With shp.ShapeRange

        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse

        With .Line
           .Visible = msoTrue
           .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
           .Transparency = 0
           .Weight = 2.25
        End With

    End With

End With
```

Answer (score 3):

`AddShape()` returns the just-added shape object, so you should be able to use something like the code below - then refer to `shp` instead of `Selection`

```
Dim shp as Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, ActiveCell.Left, _
                   ActiveCell.Top, ActiveCell.Width, ActiveCell.Height)
```